# JPanel not showing in JFrame, but JFrame still changes size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I don't know what I did, or what went wrong, but a change I made at some point in the last while has made my JPanel completely invisible. The JFrame it's nested in still changes in size to house it, and I can still toggle the content in the combobox.

In my desperation, I tried replacing the content of the SnakeSettingsPanel class with a single button, but the same thing happened - completely invisible, yet I can still interact with it. I figured it might be a computer error, so I tried restarting, but still nothing. When I tried adding a button to the frame outside of the JPanel, it worked just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SnakeSettingsPanel extends JPanel {
    public boolean quit = false;
    public boolean play = false;
    public int width = 20;
    public int height = 15;
    public Speed speed = Speed.SLOW;

    public JTextField wField;
    public JTextField hField;
    public JComboBox<Speed> sField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Snake");
        SnakeSettingsPanel settings = new SnakeSettingsPanel();
        jf.add(settings);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public SnakeSettingsPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // @author Create our labels.
        JLabel wLabel = new JLabel("Width:");
        JLabel hLabel = new JLabel("Height:");
        JLabel sLabel = new JLabel("Speed:");
        
        GridBagConstraints p = new GridBagConstraints();
            p.gridx = 0;
            p.gridy = 0;
            p.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        // @author Create the buttons, and add listeners
        JButton y = new JButton("Play");
        JButton n = new JButton("Quit");
        y.addActionListener(new PlayListener());
        n.addActionListener(new QuitListener());

        // @author Create text fields for height/width
        wField = new JTextField(15);
        wField.setText("20");
        hField = new JTextField(15);
        hField.setText("15");

        // @author Creates a combobox for selecting speed.
        Speed[] speeds = {Speed.SLOW, Speed.MEDIUM, Speed.FAST};
        sField = new JComboBox<Speed>(speeds);

        // @author Stitch everything into the panel.
        add(wLabel, p);
        p.gridx = 1;
        add(wField, p);
        p.gridx = 0;
        p.gridy = 1;
        add(hLabel, p);
        p.gridx = 1;
        add(hField, p);
        p.gridx = 0;
        p.gridy = 2;
        add(sLabel, p);
        p.gridx = 1;
        add(sField, p);
        p.gridx = 0;
        p.gridy = 3;
        add(y, p);
        p.gridx = 1;
        add(n, p);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public boolean getPlay() {
        return play;
    }

    public boolean getQuit() {
        return quit;
    }

    // @author Returns all settings as a SnakeSettings object
    public SnakeSettings getSettings() {
        return new SnakeSettings(width, height, speed);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public Speed getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    // @author Sends out the word to start a new game.
    public class PlayListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            quit = false;
            play = true;
            width = Integer.parseInt(wField.getText());
            height = Integer.parseInt(hField.getText());
            speed = (Speed) sField.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    // @author Sends out the word to shut down the program.
    public class QuitListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            quit = true;
            play = false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let this be a lesson on why you should avoid mixing Model (your application's data) with View (how it is displayed). Your `SnakeSettingsPanel` is currently both.

- As Model, it contains 3 important fields: `width`, `height`, and `speed`.
- As View, it is a full JPanel. JPanels have a *lot* of fields which you should avoid touching directly. Including  `width` and `height`, usually accessed via `getHeight` and `getWidth` -- which you are overwriting with a version that always returns the same built-in values of 20 and 15 (until the user changes those values through a UI that they cannot see).

The **fast** fix is to rename your current `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to avoid clashing with the built-in `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods of the parent JPanel class. Call them `getMyWidth()`, `getMyHeight()`, and suddenly everything works.

The **better** fix is to remove those fields and methods entirely, and store your own model attributes in a `SnakeSettings` attribute. Update it when the user clicks on play, and return it when it is requested via `getSettings()`. Less code for you, less chance of accidental name clashes with your parent `JPanel` class. This would look like:

```
    // SnakeSettingsPanel, before
    public int width = 20;
    public int height = 15;
    public Speed speed = Speed.SLOW;

    public int getWidth() {    // <-- clashes with superclass
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {   // <-- clashes with superclass
        return height;
    }
    public Speed getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public SnakeSettings getSettings() {
        return new SnakeSettings(width, height, speed);
    }

    // SnakeSettingsPanel, after
    SnakeSettings settings = new SnakeSettings();

    public SnakeSettings getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I didn't even consider that some class that was separate from the JPanel could mess with it that way. Do you know specifically how mincing naming conventions led to an invisible panel?

Comment: The panel *was* visible - but it was so tiny that nothing showed (20x15, with 10px insets, leaves very little space for any text to show). Those two attributes, width & height, control the size of visible components. Calling `pack()` makes the panel's layout manager try to find good sizes for everything; but when, after finding ideal widths & heights for your panel, the JFrame asks the panel what size it wants to be... the panel was always replying that it wants to have a size of 20x15 pixels. So that is the size that it was awarded.